# The test case for Error Boundary fails on using simulateError function, Is there any other way to make it run?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-error-boundary

I am trying to test the error-boundary component, if there is any error the error boundary component will catch it and display the right message.

I have also added the Error Boundary component code above for the reference, I also tried to mock the componentDidCatch Method while writing the test case but it did not work me as well.

```
const Something = () => null;

describe('ErrorBoundary', () => {
  it('should display an ErrorMessage if wrapped component throws', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Something />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );

    const error = new Error('test');

    wrapper.find(Something).simulateError(error);

    /* The rest fo your test */
  }
}
```

The above code is the Errorboundary.test.js usingErrorsimulator

```
    import './ErrorBoundary.scss';

import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    errorMessage: '',
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { errorMessage: error.toString() };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.logErrorToServices(error.toString(), info.componentStack);
  }

  // A fake logging service.
  logErrorToServices = console.log;

  render() {
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div className="test">
          Something went wrong, please try again or contact customer support at
          xxxx
        </div>
      );
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
ErrorBoundary.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func,
};

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: What does mean "does not work"? Throws error? Test does not pass?

Comment: Hey, did you figure it out eventually?